# Dropdown Options Hiding Behind Container - Seeking Solution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm encountering an issue with a dropdown menu where the options are getting hidden behind the container. I've included the relevant code snippet below So, I want to provide additional context to get more targeted help.

```
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12"  >
                        <div class="single-schedule " style="height: 410px;">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="icofont-prescription"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="single-content">
                                    <h4>Find A Doctor</h4>
                                    <div class="form-group has-search">
                                        <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback" style="color: black;"></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Doctors</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <select class="small-dropdown">
                                        <option value="volvo">Ahmed</option>
                                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                        <option value="fiat">Ali</option>
                                        <option value="audi">ali</option>
                                    </select>                                                               
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Specialities</h4>
                                
                                    </div>                                  
                                    <select class="small-dropdown">
                                        <option value="volvo">Neurology</option>
                                        <option value="saab">Ent</option>
                                        <option value="fiat">Phsycology</option>
                                        <option value="audi">Brain</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                             <a href="##" id="submitButton" onclick="showLoader()">Submit</a>
                                        </div>                                  
                                        <div class="col"> <a href="All_Doctors.html">See All Doctors<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>      
                                    <span class="loaderr"></span>
                                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This refers to the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) associated with the HTML document that I have furnished to you; kindly take the time to thoroughly review and examine its contents.

```
.schedule {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 230px;
}
.schedule .schedule-inner {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-30%);
    z-index:9;
}
.schedule .single-schedule {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    z-index:3;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#C31A0A;
     -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
}
.schedule .single-schedule .inner {
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding:30px;
    z-index:2;
}
.schedule .single-schedule:before{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background:#C31A0A;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
}
.schedule .single-schedule:hover:before{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.schedule .single-schedule:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you are facing and what you have tried so far to solve it? It is unclear what you get now and what you desire to get. Thanks!

Comment: @Priyas Paulzagade
I have a dropdown menu, but the options are getting hidden behind the container. How can I make them appear above the container when the dropdown is opened? Tried adjusting z-index and overflow properties with no success. Reference picture for clarity. Any solutions to make dropdown options visible above the container?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Can you share the complete code. Html and css? We need to try it on our side to resolve the issue

Comment: I Have Shared The Code Please Review It @VikramMore

Comment: @PriyasPaulzagade Kindly Review The Code I have Shared

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved by just increasing the Z-index in the css class

```
.small-dropdown {
position: relative;
z-index: 10; 
}
```

Please note that some of your elements can have higher z-index than your menu so you can just incerease the z-index
Please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: nop i tried this . didnt work !

Comment: Can you than share the code so we can reproduce the problem ? im 100% sure this solves the issue you are facing with the html structure you provided @ZahabAbbas